# Apple CarPlay entitlements missing

Tags: xcode, carplay

I need your help. Apple has been accepted my request for Apple CarPlay development. 
1. I inserted line com.apple.developer.playable-content into my file.entitlements:

[image: xCode file entitlement]

2. To my provision profile i added entitlement Apple CarPlay
   [image]
3. But when i tried to make archive from my project i have error:
   [image]

What i am doing wrong? I use and Swift language and Objective-c

Answer (score 3):

I found solution. You should disable automatically signing, and choose Provision profile with CarPlay entitlements. I suppose this answer can help for anyone.

[image]